# Hilbert polynomial for sheaves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

For graded modules $M$ (over $R$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra) one has that the Hilbert function $\varphi_M(i)=\dim_k M_i$ is asymptotically polynomial. For sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ over a projective scheme the function $i\mapsto\chi(\mathcal{F}(i))$ is polynomial (where $\chi$ is the Euler caracteristic of the sheaf, $\chi(\mathcal{G})=\oplus_i (-1)^i \dim_k H^i(X,\mathcal{G})$). I try to understand why it is not asymptotical in the situation of sheaves.

I looked at proofs and they seem to be the sames (by recurrence on the dimension of the support of the sheaf). The only difference I see is the case of dimension 0. For module dimension 0 gives vector space over $k$ that doesn't have graded component of big degree because the base ring is $k=R_0$. So asymptotically (and only asymptotically) it is 0. For sheaves dimension 0 of support gives supported by points ie skyscraper sheaves (or a sum of) and the Euler caracteristic becomes $H^0(X,\mathcal{F})$ by vanishing theorem so that $H_\mathcal{F}(i)=H^0(X,\mathcal{F}(i))$.

So I guess all is in this rather simple question: why the $H^0(X,\mathcal{F}(i))$ are all equals if $\mathcal{F}$ is a skyscraper sheaf?

If $\mathcal{F}=\widetilde{M}$ we don't have a priori that $H^0(X,\mathcal{F})=M_0$. We could take $M=\Gamma_*(\mathcal{F})=\oplus_i \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}(i))$ and it becomes true. Moreover it is clear that $\Gamma_*(\mathcal{F}(l))=\Gamma_*(\mathcal{F})(l)$ so that wee have $H^0(X,\mathcal{F}(i))=M_i$. Conclusion: in this situation $H_\mathcal{F}=H_M$ and I have a problem because the $H_M$ are not polynomial but only asymptotically polynomial.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a skyscraper sheaf defined on $X$ with support a closed point $x$. Then so is $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{O}(i)$ and they have isomorphic spaces of stalks at $x$. So they’re isomorphic sheaves...

Comment: I'm agree with your argumentation: the key fact is $\mathcal{O}_X(i)_P=\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$.Do you see what is going wrong in my argumentation in last paragraph?

Comment: In your last paragraph you’re only considering the $H^0$ term when the Euler characteristic includes the other cohomology terms...

Comment: Ok so my mistake seems to be: $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})= H^i(\mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{F}),\mathcal{F})$

Comment: No, that part is sound. But for $\tilde{M}$ to be a skyscraper sheaf, you need a very special $M$.

Comment: If $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})=H^i(\mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{F}),\mathcal{F})$ was true, as $\mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{F})$ is zero dimensional so the $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})=0$ for $i>0$ so $\chi(\mathcal{F})=H^0(X,\mathcal{F})$, no???